# Delete cache on Apollo 3

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo

Hi I'm making a next js app and I'm using Apollo Client v3 to fetch from a GraphQL API, but I'm having some issues.
I want when the user press a button to change the rol from user to admin or vice versa remove all the cache, for the app to show only the new content. Thanks in advance!

Comment: search for 'reset apollo cache [on logout]"

Answer (score 0):

Apollo client use an InMemory Cache to store data.

There is several ways to update that cache after an operation (mutation) :

- If the mutation concern the same entity than on the query, you can update it automaticaly with an update mutation that return the modified entity id and new data.
  https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#updating-a-single-existing-entity
- Else, you can configure the cache data to update manually with the `update` callback
  https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates
- If you prefer to not directly modify cache but refetch some queries, you can use the refetchQuery callback
  https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#rerunning-queries-after-a-mutation

Comment: I'm no making mutations, I have the same query but with distinct variables according to the rol of the user.